# Can we add new column to a data frame from another data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. I created a data frame `df1` using pyspark which have 10 columns. Then I created a temp view for `df1` , `tempviewdf1`. Then I selected 5 columns from the temp view and made another dataframe `df2`. Now I want to add 6th column to `df2` from `df1`. Is it possible?

I saw `withColumn()` method, but I realized it only works if the column name is same.

Comment: If possible, include the 6th column in the beginning. It's possible to add afterwards but it will add complexity (you can for example use `join` if you have an id column).

Comment: @shaido how to add 6th column in the beginning?

Comment: You said you selected 5 columns from df1 to make df2. Is it not possible to add a 6th column here? If you add your current code and some simplified dataframes to illustrate the problem it would be easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@victor
Say your Df1 looks like below,

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|key|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   1|   2|   3|   4|   7|   8|
|  2|   4|   3|   4|   5|   8|   9|
|  3|   9|   4|   5|   6|   9|  10|
```

and created a view

```
  Df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tempviewdf1")
```

and making a select on few columns from it and making it as Df2

```
val Df2 = spark.sql("""select key, col1, col2, col3 , col4 from tempviewdf1""")
```

say now you want to add col5 part of your Df2, just add those in select..

```
val Df2 = spark.sql("""select key, col1, col2, col3 , col4, col5 from tempviewdf1""")
```

but why you want to create a view and select a column out of it and create a Df2 ?

you can just make it like below ( this is spark-scala, similarly you can see in pyspark)

```
val Df2 = Df1.select("key","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
```

even you can do other way, like dropping columns.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions